# How can I setup a simple Mercurial back-up solution from a workstation to server?

Tags: macos, mercurial, windows-server, atlassian-sourcetree

First, a confession. In about 10 years of professional development, I've never used a source control system.  There, that feels better.  My historical setup (as recommended by management, ha!) has been to create dated folders on a server and copy-and-paste my data into it each evening.

I've known for a long time that a much better, manageable solution would be to use git or Mercurial to manage my source but I've never taken the time to learn any of these new tools because myold system has always worked well enough for my needs as the lone developer for every project I've ever worked on.

I have finally change this setup.  I've installed Mercurial on my Mac, which after a bit of reading, I prefer over git.  As a GUI front-end, I have installed SourceTree which appears to be easy to use and quite friendly.  The problem I am having is that I can't find a very simple, straight-forward walkthrough for setting up a server repository that I use for pushing changes to each evening.  I'm sure it's there, I just can't find it.

I've honestly tried to Google this, but there is something about the term "SourceTree".  I can't find anything useful because half of the information I find is in regards to using git and it tends to involve pushing a project to a site like `github.com`, which is not pertinent in my case.

Additionally, I have skimmed the Mercurial documentation and I still may not be entirely clear about the full commit/update/push/pull/branch/merge concept.  I just want to get something setup rather fast that will back-up and track the changes of my projects, without having to be a source control guru.

**How do I setup a simple repository on a Windows network server, and push and pull changes each evening?**  My company want me to store my data in a personal folder, on a network share that is backed up to tape and is then stored off site.

I'm sure it has to be simple.  I just want to be sure that I'm doing it correctly so that in the case that I need to access a back up, it is there and can be easily pulled... or branched.. or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it depends on the kind of the server you are going to use.

Let's assume it's not a Windows server (just a guess, as you're a Mac user). Let's also assume that right now you only need it for yourself, not for a bunch of users.

Then the simplest way is to use SSH. Suppose the server is `server`, and you have an account `rlh` there. You'll need to have a public/private key pair for a seamless access (no need to enter the password on each pull/push). You'll need to install Mercurial on the server as well, obviously.

On the server, create a repo (in your home dir, for example):

```
rlh@mac$ ssh server
rlh@server$ mkdir myproject
rlh@server$ cd myproject
rlh@server$ hg init
```

On your machine, clone the repo:

```
rlh@mac$ hg clone ssh://rlh@server/myproject myproject
```

The default target will be set automatically, and you should be able to pull/push with no additional configuration.

Feel free to ask if you have a question regarding this.

Comment: This is actually being pushed to a Windows share, from a Mac.  However, I think I can figure out how to make the necessary changes to your code to make this work.  If I setup my project by command line, will SourceTree automatically see the repositories?  Will default target be my project folder on my machine, or the server.  I would assume the server, but I'm not sure.  I want to make sure I get the semantics correct.

Answer (score 2):

When searching for hosting solutions, best not to include the term SourceTree in your query — SourceTree is just a front-end tool that is in principle unrelated to Mercurial hosting. That might explain the lack of useful information.

Here is an overview of ways to set up Mercurial servers:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories

Personally I’m using plain hgweb and that has served me well.

Also I would recommend to consider using a hosting service such as BitBucket or Google Code. It requires much less effort to set up and maintain. Here is an overview of Mercurial hosting services:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MercurialHosting

Personally I’m also considering moving my self-hosted Mercurial repositories over to BitBucket, because of reduced maintenance overhead, and also it has functionality like bug tracker, wiki etc.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't mind using a hosted source, rather than a local server (which is a Windows server, btw).  The problem is, that I work for a company, and and using a hosted source like this is highly against company policy.  Instead, they want me to store my data in a personal folder, on a network share that is backed up to tape and is then stored off site.  Also, I asked about using SourceTree because I'd prefer to use a simple front-end that allows me to see the differences in my changes.  I guess this is primarily a SourceTree-on-top-of-Mercurial question, rather than being about Hg.

Comment: @RLH: As I noted in my answer thread, Windows share isn't the optimal solution in terms of reliability, and as far as I understand what the company actually wants _is_ reliability. Thus, if you are willing to invest some effort, and are able to convince your company the matter is important, consider setting up a Mercurial server on of your company servers. The first link given in this answer provides a good overview.

Comment: Note that you can use a repository located on a network share as shared repository to pull from/push to. Even though not ideal, it’s a relatively common set-up for starters. As long as the SMB share is on a Windows machine, it should work OK. I think there are some issues with Linux-hosted Samba shares. But if you can set up a real server, it would be much better of course :).